# Usage of "when to do something"

Tags: grammar

I wrote a sentence like this " She is homesick and uncertain when to go back to her home country."

Is that sentence correct? Is there a usage of "when to do something"?

Comment: The sentence is grammatically correct but it depends on the context. Perhaps you mean "uncertain when **she can** go back..."

Answer (score 2):

you are not wrong at all!
the main usage of **"when to do something"** , is focused on time.

so the sentence you have is technically correct but may not get to the meaning of what you want to say.

Your original sentence:
"She is homesick and uncertain when to go back to her home country."

**Literally** means: "She is homesick and uncertain what **TIME** to back to her home country"

What you might mean: "She is homesick and uncertain when she **CAN** go back to her home country"

The reason of adding **CAN** to the sentence is good because it is more specific to add to the meaning of the sentence. Adding the word **CAN** is the same as saying "when is she ABLE to go back?"